# Python to search for add numbers intelligently

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I've created a script that outputs timesheets for the work I'm doing in this format:

```
To:     JOE DOE

Client:     JOE DOE

Case #:     14-M-123        Charge: BREAKING AND ENTERING

----------------------------------------------------------------------------



12-12-12    research                1.2 hrs 89 miles
        Another task 
        yet another task

12-12-13    Conf. w/ magistrate ct          1.8 hrs 88 miles

11-11-11    Yadayada                0.0 hrs 10 miles
```

Is there a simple way to search through each file, and add the hrs and miles columns separately?

I'm assuming you would use regular expressions?

Comment: My apologies for the hyperlink, didn't know that wasn't kosher. 
Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
text = file('filename').read()
numbers = re.findall(r'([0-9.]+) hrs ([0-9]+) miles', text)
hours = sum(float(x[0]) for x in numbers)
miles = sum(int(x[1]) for x in numbers)
```

Something like that should work.

What it does is search through your text to find instances of a number (optionally with a decimal place) followed by `hrs` and another (no decimal place) followed by `miles`.

I've made several assumptions such as there being precisely one space between the numbers and their labels and between the two columns and that miles are always integers and hours are not but hopefully you can adapt as necessary.

Comment: I think this is what will work best for me. I'm pretty sure there's a way to make a user inputted number into a decimal (54 --> 54.0), so this is probably what I'll do.

Comment: ``float(54) == 54.0`` but I'm not sure why you need that. Maybe I didn't explain something well?

Comment: So if the user inputs hours as an integer, i can gurantee that they're found.

Comment: That regular expression doesn't have to match a ``.`` so it will match ``54`` just as well as it matches ``54.0``. If you wanted the miles to potentially be decimals too, you could also add a dot in there (and make it a float in the sum too).

Answer (score 2):

Once your file is always in the same format, split will work fine:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    tot_miles = 0
    tot_hrs = 0
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.endswith("miles"):
            spl = line.rsplit(None,4)
            h, m = spl[1],spl[3]
            tot_miles += int(m)
            tot_hrs += float(h)
    print("Total hrs = {}\nTotal miles = {}".format(tot_hrs,tot_miles))

Total hrs = 3.0
Total miles = 187
```

Comment: The `if` can just be `if line.endswith('miles')` as if it's empty it can't end with it:) Also, I'd split the other way... `line.rsplit(None, 4)` then take the 1st and 3rd result - not a big deal, but it makes it a bit more explicit and robust as negative indexing can always returning something even if it's not correct, while direct indexing can raise an `IndexError` indicating some form of formatting error.

Comment: @JonClements, True,  thanks. I had started doing it differently the if line is indeed redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn this around and ask a different question: your script *outputs* these time sheets, correct? Is the source data still available? If so, it will be much more reliable if you can regenerate the time sheets with the additional columns added in your templates. Regular expressions and other parsing are going to be more difficult and time consuming, not to mention brittle when you update the script in the future.

Any time I write a report generation script, I add flags to regenerate previous data as if it is being run on a given date. (This makes testing easier, as well.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the script that outputs the data in the first place, I recommend you change it so that it outputs CSV data instead (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

In addition to being trivially parsable by any other Python program, it gives you the advantage of being readable and modifiable in Excel.